# Why isn't the javax.smartcardio package in the Java SE 7/8 API?

Tags: api, smartcard, java

I searched for a while and I can't find the Java package `javax.smartcardio` in the official API of Java. I looked through these two different Java APIs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

I thought `javax.smartcardio` is an official package of Java. Now I wonder why it isn't foundable in the official APIs?

The only way you can find the package is over a search engine in the Internet. Google led me to this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html

Comment: You might want to look at other alternatives though. It seems there are a couple of libraries created to provide the smartcardio functionality.