# configure jdk for javacard import in netbeans

Tags: javacard

I am trying out a javacard program copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949239/can-a-java-web-application-access-a-smart-card-reader-on-a-remote-work-station) but my system can't find import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal. How can I get the imports or configure jdk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.smartcardio - javadocs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214042/javax-smartcardio-javadocs)

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960521/why-isnt-the-javax-smartcardio-package-in-the-java-se-7-8-api